# Trying to find derivative of function using python

Tags: python, math, calc

I am trying to find the derivative of this function:

y = 100e^-0.0482t

This is the code I have:

```
import math
from sympy import *
import numpy as np
x = Symbol('x')
y = (math.exp(-.0482 * x) * 100)
yprime = y.diff(x)
yprimerep = y.diff(5)
yprime
print(yprime)
```

I am getting an error of:
TypeError: can't convert expression to float

Ive looked through various meanings of that error and I dont get it. any idea what Im doing wrong?

Comment: What is `Symbol('x')`?

Comment: I was trying to define 'x' from the equation (i used 'x' instead of 't' in the code)

Comment: Try using sympy exp instead of math.exp.

Comment: Ok I tried that, how would I define sympy? I am getting the error
NameError: name 'sympy' is not defined

Comment: Because you have `from sympy import *`.  So, exp should be in your namespace and you should be able to say `y = exp(-.0482 * x) * 100`.  Better yet would be using `import sympy` instead of `from sympy import *` and then you could use `sympy.exp`

Comment: sorry for so many questions im still new to this, I changed what you said, and now I am seeing an error for not defining symbol

name 'Symbol' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? It finds the derivative and the 5th derivative, unless you are trying to evaluate the derivative with x=5

```
import sympy

x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = (sympy.exp(-.0482 * x) * 100)
yprime = y.diff(x) # get derivative
print yprime # print derivative
print y.diff(x, 5) # print 5th derivative
```

The problem with your code was passing a math exp statement to sympy.

I'm not too familiar with sympy, but I believe if you want to substitute in 5 for x, you can do

```
yprime.subs(x,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to import math and numpy.
Just use sympy, because the values in other modules may complicate things and functions of a module cannot understand values derived from other modules. As a principle, try to stick one module about math calculations.

As of calculating the value of the derivative at certain point, you can use lambdify() from the sympy. It converts the string to function which lets you calculate the value at that location.

For example:

```
from sympy import *
    
x = Symbol('x')
    
f = input("Enter the function: ")
    
f_derivative = Derivative(f, x)
f_derivative = f_derivative.doit() #do the derivative and assign it to variable
print(f_derivative)
    
f = lambdify(x, f)
f_derivative = lambdify(x, f_derivative) #convert it to function
    
userInput = float(input("Try critical point: "))
print("Your input: ", userInput)
    
result = f_derivative(userInput) #pass the point to the function and assign it to variable

print("Result: ", result)
```